# design breaks for medium size device

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, responsive-design

I have developed a form using material-ui and its grid feature. However, I am getting an issue in the medium size device and tablet. How could i fix that? The issue can be seen when resizing the browser or in responsive tool. I have created a working demo in codesandbox.

https://codesandbox.io/s/kwrlpxjwko

Here is the full code

style.css

```
.slogan {
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding: 3em 0;
}

.limiter {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 10em;
}

.container-login {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: stretch;
  justify-content: center;
}

.wrap-login {
  width: 500px;
  min-height: 60vh;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 2px;
  position: relative;
}

.login-more {
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  width: calc(100% - 740px);
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

/* tablet and desktop should have similar login-more size 
 in mobile it should be hidden */

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .login-more {
    width: calc(100% - 950px);
  }
}

.login-more::before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 148, 217, 0.83);
}

.login-form {
  width: 100%;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.login-form-title {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 39px;
  color: #333333;
  line-height: 1.2;
  text-align: left;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.p-l-50 {
  padding-left: 50px;
}
.p-r-50 {
  padding-right: 50px;
}
.p-t-50 {
  padding-top: 50px;
}
.p-b-50 {
  padding-bottom: 50px;
}

.input-field {
  padding: 25px 0 !important;
}

.login-banner-text {
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  font-size: 3em;
  margin-top: 20px;
}


<div className="limiter">
        <div className="container-login">
          <div className="login-more" style={styles.loginBackground}>
            <h1 className="login-banner-text">
              Your Springboard <br /> to Success
            </h1>
          </div>
          <div className="wrap-login p-l-50 p-r-50 p-t-72 p-b-50">
            <Register
              handleSubmit={this.handleSubmit}
              handleChange={this.handleChange}
              handleCheckbox={this.handleCheckbox}
              userValue={this.state.userValue}
              errors={this.state.errors}
            />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Register.js

```
 <Grid container spacing={24}>
      <form className="login-form validate-form" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <span className="login-form-title p-b-59">Sign Up</span>
        <Grid item xs={12}>
          <Field
            id="fullName"
            name="fullName"
            placeholder="Fullname"
            className="input-field"
            onChange={handleChange}
            value={fullName}
            fullWidth
            component={MaterialTextField}
            {...fullName}
          />
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={12}>
          <Field
            id="emai"
            name="email"
            onChange={handleChange}
            value={email}
            placeholder="Email"
            className="input-field"
            fullWidth
            component={MaterialTextField}
          />
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={12}>
          <Field
            id="password"
            name="password"
            onChange={handleChange}
            value={password}
            className="input-field"
            placeholder="password"
            type="password"
            fullWidth
            component={MaterialTextField}
          />
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={12}>
          <div className="terms">
            <FormControlLabel
              control={
                <Checkbox
                  id="agree-term"
                  type="checkbox"
                  onChange={handleCheckbox}
                  name="agreeTerm"
                />
              }
              label="I agree to terms and conditions"
            />
          </div>
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={12}>
          <div className="buttonContainer">
            <Button
              variant="raised"
              disabled={pristine || submitting || !agreeTerm}
              id="create-account"
              type="submit"
            >
              Sign Up
            </Button>
          </div>
        </Grid>
      </form>
      <Grid item xs={12}>
        <div className="form-footer">
          <p>
            Already have an account,<a href="">Log in</a>
          </p>
        </div>
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
```

How do i make it responsive for all the devices?

Expected behavior - it should be like the image for desktop and tablet devices but no left blue screen for mobile devices.

[expected design for desktop and tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VHCfE.png)

Comment: Can you tell us/show us a picture what is expected behavior and what is the difference from current state? I can see that form breaks somehow. The question is, how it should be working?

Comment: @LudovitMydla updated my question with image

Answer (score 0):

So. How about adding media query to hide the whole image?

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .login-more {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

And you also have some quirky paddings on your elements:

```
.limiter {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 10em; /* I think this is unnecessary big. Use some percentages. Perhaps 5%? */
}
```

And one last thing. Using `box-sizing: border-box;` might help with your design overflowing the width of the screen.

My sandbox [over here](https://codesandbox.io/s/m7jv7r1j39)

Comment: is this working in the medium size device like in tablet?

Comment: i get following https://i.imgur.com/77ILzbp.png. The blue screen is hidden for medium devices and full name field border line has some issue

Comment: First of all, you need to specify, what `medium size` device is. What is the screen width for those devices. Then you can specify any "break points" in `@media` directive and from that any kind of design/layout you need to achieve.